# XmlTextReader Invalid character exception - character is '¢' symbol

Tags: c#, xml

I am getting

> Invalid character in the given encoding.

exception when trying to `Read()` text inside an xml element that contains a '¢' symbol.

the xml element looks like this:

```
<COMMENTS>NOTE:
         5¢                                   50                                          10,000
        25¢                                  10                                             2,000</COMMENTS>
```

I tried using .Net's XmlConvert class (it claims to fix these types of issues), but it does not detect '¢' symbol as invalid.

```
  public PaytableReaderStrategy(string filepath)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filepath))
            throw new ApplicationException("Could not read .xml from provided filepath.");


        string content = File.ReadAllText(filepath);

        if (!IsValidXmlString(content))
            File.WriteAllText(filepath, RemoveInvalidXmlChars(content));


        Reader = new XmlTextReader(filepath);
    }

    private static string RemoveInvalidXmlChars(string text)
    {
        var validXmlChars = text.Where(ch => XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(ch)).ToArray();
        return new string(validXmlChars);
    }

    private static bool IsValidXmlString(string text)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlConvert.VerifyXmlChars(text);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Is there a .Net-style solution to this issue that handles not just '¢' symbol but detects and removes any offending symbol?

Comment: How are you getting this error?  There's nothing wrong with having `¢` in an XML file, it's not illegal in any sense.  See [this demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i5YF3H), for example.

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't be using `XmlTextReader` since .NET 2.0.  Look at `XmlReader.Create`.

Comment: @Charles: I changed my code to use XmlReader.Create and received the same exception. The demo (thank you for sharing) is not using either class and is instead using XDocument. If you know how to resolve this issue using the .Net classes that I have in my example above that would be preferred.

Comment: `XDocument.Load` uses `XmlReader` internally.  The example was supposed to show you that this isn't an invalid character. I suspect the XML is a red herring - perhaps it's file encoding.  Can you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I am using the default encoding, UTF-8. Simply copy/paste the xml element I provided in to a text file and run the code above, using the filename that you saved it under.

Comment: I can reproduce if I do exactly that, saving using notepad.  This means my file isn't UTF8, it's ANSI.  If you've done the same, then that's your problem - you're decoding an ANSI file using UTF8.  You'd see the issue if you inspect the result of `File.ReadAllText` - `¢` is replaced with garbage.

Comment: Curious, how did you create a tiny url for the demo? I just created an example to share with you but 'share' just tries to create a widjit. Thanks for showing me that website!

Comment: Click Share then copy the link that's shown.

Comment: like this? <iframe width="100%" height="475" src="https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/VSXwGk" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: when i click share it allows me to create a widjit (only) no option for a tinyurl

Comment: i'll take a look at the ansi encoding. Thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: Charles, you answered this. It was the encoding. I'd like to award you. please post the answer.

Comment: There is no "the ANSI encoding"; there are dozens. Even without that issue, if you don't know what encoding a file uses, you've got data loss. You can't properly create an XML file by pasting and saving unless you change the charset declaration internal to the document. A real XML writer would do that automatically—because it is part of the job. Then you can use a real XML reader that would figure it out.

Comment: @Tom: i suppose I'm a newb: it just seems like text to me I didn't realize how nuanced it could be with the different character sets - especially with international character sets. Curious, how do you "change the charset declaration" if you are using, let's say notepad++ or some other text editor?

Comment: When you or a library writes an XML file, choose a character encoding,say UTF-8 and change the XML declaration to to indicate that, for example: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`, then encode the document and save the bytes. Now, you can transfer the document to another system and not have to also transmit which encoding is used, as you would have to in other scenarios. With Notepad++, you would type in the XML declaration, select an encoding from the Encoding menu and then save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alluded in the comments, the issue is that your file will be decoded using `Encoding.UTF8` by default, but your file is not encoded in UTF8.  This means that characters outside the normal ASCII set will not decode correctly.

You can specify your encoding by using a `StreamReader` and passing this to `XmlReader.Create`:

```
var sr = new StreamReader(filepath, Encoding.Default);
Reader = XmlReader.Create(sr);
```

Note that you should ensure both `Reader` and `sr` are disposed once you have finished reading the file.